# How do I generate a table of permutations from a list with cyclical redundancy eliminated?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm currently creating the permutations in a horribly inefficient manner; [generating a table with duplicates, then eliminating dupes with a QUERY](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-QNFfOVaLIPDKXWRktJdo7tqBQGfsHo2eWTvkjhmeZ0/edit?usp=sharing).

The results (125 rows > 20 rows) is manageable with a list of 5, but not with a list of 15 (3375 > 910 rows), and especially not when doing larger cycles (4 => 50625 > 8190; 5 => 759375 > 72072)

Creating a table 10 times as long as needed to get the resulting table is horribly inefficient; there must be a better way to jump directly to the final result without an intermediary.

Answer (score -1):

if you do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(B2:B)),CHAR(9)))&" "&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(A2:A))),CHAR(9))))
```

you can salvage full potential of Google Sheets:

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v8Cmifj4oB_30DoIeQN461Db6LbNSKLPGkxQXNV8rlE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The goal is to get the right-hand result (in my linked example) without having to generate the larger left-hand intermediary table. You are only generating the larger table; that's not the goal.